# using a first time boolean c++ or java

Tags: java, c++, boolean

I usually use a boolean 'firstTime' like this:

in C++:

```
bool firsTime = true;
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
    if (firstTime) {
        //do something just once
        firstTime = false;
    }
    else {
        //do the usual thing
    }
}
```

in java it would be the same using a boolean instead a bool so I don't put the code.

The questin is, is there anyway in java or c/c++ to use a bool/boolean in an if clause and automatically assign to that bool/boolean the value false?

I know it seems a nonsense but it would save my code A LOT of lines because I've a lot of base cases and in big fors or whiles that is critical.

I do want to know if there is anyway to put a value to false after using it in an if clause. I know that in a for or while we can just use:

```
if (i == 0)
```

But I was also thinking in calls to functions that needs to know things and that usually is referenced by bools.

Comment: Just make a class that does exactly what you want. Just imagine the ideal interface for your code, and make a class (or macro) that makes that interface work.

Comment: I'm not looking for an EXACT solution for the code above but actually lookinf for the if (bool) and then bool = false in one line.. (look at the last paragraph I added now ;). Thanks!

Comment: Check my answer, does it in one line for C++ - you could write a java method that does it too

Comment: Write a wrapper class named `Flag` which has `bool test_and_clear()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't have a count already, you can use one instead of a boolean

```
long counter = 0;
for(String arg: args) {
    if(counter++ == 0) {
       // first
    }
}
```

An alternative which uses a boolean is

```
boolean first = true;
for(String arg: args) {
    if(first && !(first = false)) {
       // first
    }
}
```

---

For sets there is a similar pattern

```
Set<String> seen = ...
for(String arg: args) {
    if(seen.add(arg)) {
       // first time for this value of arg as its only added once.
    }
}
```

Comment: I think this one is the best answer, because if, instead of using a bool/boolean I use a counter with this if clause (adding one to the counter AFTER the if clause) then there's no need to do anything else. Anyway I would put somewhere in the code a counter = 1 to be sure not to get a OF. I'll wait for some another answer but I think this one is very good.

Comment: That second solution, deliberately using an assignment in an `if`, is very confusing. I'd never use that in real code.

Comment: @Jesper: Yeah, I was doing that it my answer too, but thought otherwise because I also thought i was overly confusing.  A function/method which took a reference made it cleaner

Answer (score 7):

I'd just change the condition to

```
if ( i == 0 )
{ 
}
//...
```

and get rid of the extra variable altogether.

**EDIT** After seeing all suggestions on how to do this in one line, I can only come to one conclusion - **DON'T**. Just use what you have, it's much **much** clearer.

Comment: Good, as long as you’re not using a range-based `for` loop.

Comment: I put the for or while code, and as you say, that would be a good answer but I was actually (also) thinking in different functions which also look for that (I'm going to edit my question).

Comment: what about if he wants to use a java for each loop?

Comment: @LuchianGrigore After reading your edit and looking at his code again, I have to agree actually. there is something very nice about being able to just read off "if (firstTime)". You immediately know exactly what is going on even if you are not author of code. (+1 for the edit!)

Answer (score 4):

There is a C++ - specific solution that uses conversion operator to build a single-use guard:

```
class first_guard {
    bool val;
public:
    first_guard() : val(true) {}
    operator bool() { bool res = val; val = false; return res; }
};
```

Here is how you use the guard:

```
first_guard first;
for (int i = 0 ; i != 5 ; i++) {
    if(!first) {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
}
```

This code prints `1 2 3 4`, skipping `0`.

Lack of conversion operators prevents you from replicating this solution in Java.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (int i = 0, firstTime = 1; i < v.size(); i++, firstTime = 0) {
```

Comment: that looks very very good in the case that we have a for or while (or some kinds of loops). Thanks! But, there isn't a way to do exactly what I said? (knowing that your answer would go perfectly for the code proposed!!)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit: See Luchian's edit about using what you have. I agree. It is very clear.**

Why not just pull the first loop iteration out of the loop?

```
//do something just once (if needed, so check)
for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
    //do the usual thing
}
```

Now if there is some chance that you may not do this first thing you would need to check for that, but a lot of times you will probably at least do one iteration.

Comment: You still need get a comparison, because you have to check for size 0. If it's inside the loop, you don't need that check.

Comment: Should check for v.size() > 0 before doing the thing just once

Answer (score 1):

If the first iteration should just have some extra initialization in addition to the usual "stuff" (rather than "instead of the usual stuff"), I'd consider something like this:

```
for (int i=0, do_first_time_stuff(); i<v.size(); i++) {
    do_other_stuff();
}
```

Another possibility would be something like:

```
Initialization();
std::for_each(v.begin()+1, v.end(), loop_body);
```

Comment: These both do first time stuff even if there is no first time.

Answer (score 0):

I would just do whatever you are trying to do the first time outside of the for loop, then start the iterator one up.

```
if (v.size() > 0) {
    /* first time code */
}
for (int i = 1; i < v.size(); i++) {
    /* second time or more */
}
```

If you're using a foreach loop, your solution is pretty solid.

Comment: You still need get a comparison, because you have to check for size 0. If it's inside the loop, you don't need that check.

Answer (score 0):

why not do something like:

```
void firstTime() {
    // do stuff
}

void doWork(int i) {
    // do stuff
}

firstTime();
for(int i = 1; i<v.size();i++) {
 doWork(i);
}
```

Comment: Because that calls `firstTime` even if there is no first time!

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using the contents of the list in your first time activity.

```
if(v.size() >=1 ){
  //do Something for 1 time
}
for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++) {
        //do the usual thing
}
```

If you need the content of the list then use

```
if ( i == 0 )
{ 
}
```

as suggested by Luchian Grigore

Answer (score 0):

You could try (C++):

```
bool checkFirst(bool& first)
{
  bool result = first;
  first = false;
  return result;
}

bool firstTime=true;
// loop here { 
if (checkFirst(firstTime))
{
  // do firsttime stuff
} else {
 // do regular stuff
}
// } // end loop
```

Java:

```
public class CheckFirst
{
  private boolean first;

  public CheckFirst()
  {
    first = true;
  }

  boolean check()
  {
    boolean result = first;
    first = false;
    return result;
  }
}

CheckFirst first = new CheckFirst();
// loop here {
if (first.check()) {
  // do first stuff
} else {
  // do regular stuff
}
// } // end loop
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be &&? Short circuit evaluation says `firstTime=false` is never called.

Comment: Wrong. Because of short-circuiting, the second argument to the `||` - `firstTime = false` won't get executed.

Answer (score 0):

I would try something like this,it works, but I'm not sure if it's totally the right way to go.( http://ideone.com/Bcjva )

```
boolean boo = true;
if( !((boo) ? (boo = !boo) : boo)) //enters the if successfully, but inside,prints boo as false.
     System.out.println(boo);
```

Comment: It would add more lines at the code (in assembler) because of the if clause. This works but adds lines, actually! thank you anyway

Comment: You were going for the `if` clause anyway. But even I would say @PeterLawrey has given a very sensible solution.